# Node.Js ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE Error? Worked perfectly on MAMP

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am coding a node.js app, after I transferred it from my development environment to server, it refused to connect to the database, and spew out this error:

```
ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE
```

I am using the Node.js MYSQL module, and the reference code from its page.
 How can I resolve this? the database on my server works perfectly for other things.

MYSQL connection code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'usr', //just using root for my personal testing.
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'dbmain'
});
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `db`', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code of mysql connection?

Comment: I take it no one knows?

Comment: Are you sure that mysql server doesn't require an ssl connection? If you have an old version of mysql server you can try to set insecureAuth: true setting in createConnection() function.

Comment: Its the newest version of Mysql. how would I set insecureAuth? incase it is still a old version.

Comment: You can find more information about insecureAuth in node-mysql docs.